# how to check one field with two values in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

```
$input = Input::all();


$user = User::where(function($q) {
          $q->where('email', $input['email'] )
            ->orWhere('email', $input['emails'][0]['value'] );
      })
      ->first();

   print_r($user);die;
```

Always says Undefined variable: input
        What is the best way to compare email with two values please guide

Comment: why dont you do a print_r($input); and check what it is printing

Comment: What out put do you get by dd($input['emails'][0]['value'])?

Comment: You need to add `use` to the function clause.

Answer (score 3):

Add `use($input)` to pass the `$input` variable to the closure scope:

```
User::where(function ($q) use ($input) {
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: It says Undefined index: email

Comment: Array
(
    [kind] => plus#person
    [etag] => "s/s"
    [birthday] => 1996-08-18
    [gender] => male
    [emails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => s@gmail.com
                    [type] => account
                )

        )

Comment: @AmanJoshi that's completely different error. This means now you can access the `$input` variable inside the closure, but the variable doesn't have `email`. Do `$input[emails][0][0]['value']` instead of `$input['email']`

Comment: There are two condition where i get email and emails array need to set both

Comment: Yes @Alexey Mezenin what is the way it skip if email is undefined and will check emails array if exists. 

It can be either email variable or emails array i want check user's email from inputs value's

Comment: @Alexy see I'll get two value either email or emails array So here if I do check $input['emails'][0]['value'] will get exact value but there is no email key in array so it says invalid index email I want it will skip if email is undefined wheather you have emails array vice versa

Answer (score 0):

```
User::where(function($q) use ($input) {
    $q->where('email', $input['emails'][0]['value']);
    if (array_key_exists('email', $input)) {
        $q->orWhere('email', $input['emails'][0]['value']);
    }
})
```

but make sure that you always have this value ***$input['emails'][0]['value']***