# Trying to access variable outside laravel collection->each

Tags: php, laravel, collections, each, laravel-5.5

I am trying to access variable outside laravel collection->each, but I get ..

```
Undefined variable: headers
```

Here's my code:

```
public function bulkCoding(Request $request) {

    Excel::load($request->file, function($reader) {
        $headers  = $reader->get()->first()->keys();

        // Loop through all sheets
        $reader->each(function($sheet) {
            $headers->each(function ($title) {
                dd($title);
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: undefined variable what??

Comment: @Sohel0415, updated.

Comment: you are using wrong variable `$headers` instead of `$sheet`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use the `use()` to [pass variable inside the closure scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366081/1227923):

```
each(function($sheet) use($headers) {
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks :)