# How to build MySQL query with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel query like this but I got error like this

> Undefined variable: keyword

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
                    ->leftJoin('users', 'bookings.manager_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->leftJoin('projects', 'bookings.pr_project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
                    ->leftJoin('resources', 'bookings.pr_resource_id', '=', 'resources.id')
                    ->Where('unavailable','=','0')
                    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                        $query->Where('users.name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                            ->Where('projects.project_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                           ->Where('resources.r_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
                    })
                    ->orderBy('bookings.pr_working_date', 'desc')
                    ->paginate($perPage);
```

Now below query how to convert in Laravel

```
   select * from bookings left join users on bookings.manager_id=users.id left join projects on bookings.pr_project_id=projects.id left join resources on bookings.pr_resource_id=resources.id where unavailable='0' AND (users.name like '%One Web Series%' or projects.project_name like '%One Web Series%' or resources.r_name like '%One Web Series%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the necessary variables from the parent scope into the closure with the use keyword . (i.e)

```
Where(function ($query) use($keyword)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to [add the `use()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366081/1227923) like this to pass the variable into the closure scope:

```
function ($query) use($keyword) {
```

Answer (score 3):

use `use()`-

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'bookings.manager_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->leftJoin('projects', 'bookings.pr_project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
                ->leftJoin('resources', 'bookings.pr_resource_id', '=', 'resources.id')
                ->Where('unavailable','=','0')
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use($keyword){
                    $query->Where('users.name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                        ->Where('projects.project_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                       ->Where('resources.r_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
                })
                ->orderBy('bookings.pr_working_date', 'desc')
                ->paginate($perPage);
```