# Undefined variable. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter my results. For this i have following query:

```
$destinations = $request['destinations'];
        if($request->has('destinations'))
        {
            $trips = Trip::where('status','=',1)->whereHas('destinations', function($q) {
            $q->where('destinationsid', '=', $destinations);
            })->get();
        }else{
             echo "No destination provided";
        }
```

But I'm getting undefined variable $destinations. If i replace $destinations with any id (6) it shows results. 
I have also tried to echo $destinations outside the query, it is returning array. What is wrong here? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the `use($destination)` after `function($q)`:

```
$destinations = $request['destinations'];

if($request->has('destinations'))
{
     $trips = Trip::where('status','=',1)->whereHas('destinations', function($q) use($destinations) {
        $q->where('destinationsid', '=', $destinations);
     })->get();
} else {
        echo "No destination provided";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You [need to add `use()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366081/1227923) to the closure to pass variables. For example:

```
->whereHas('destinations', function($q) use($destinations) {
```

Or, you could just use the [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) global helper:

```
->whereHas('destinations', function($q) {
    $q->where('destinationsid', request('destinations'));
```

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `destinations` variable in your where closure:

```
$destinations = $request['destinations'];
    if($request->has('destinations'))
    {
        $trips = Trip::where('status','=',1)->whereHas('destinations', function($q) use ($destinations){
        $q->where('destinationsid', '=', $destinations);
        })->get();
    }else{
         echo "No destination provided";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use destinations variable in your where closure:

```
if($request->has('destinations'))
{

    $destinations = $request['destinations'];
    $trips = Trip::where('status','=',1)->whereHas('destinations', function($q) use ($destinations){
    $q->where('destinationsid', '=', $destinations);
    })->get();
```