# How can a variable can be accessed inside the QueryBuilder in `Laravel`

Tags: laravel

How can I access `$data` inside the QueryBuilder in `Laravel`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = [1,2,3,4];
    echo User::whereHas('books', function($query){
            $query->whereIn('id', $data);
         })->get();
}
```

Above code shows the error

```
ErrorException thrown with message "Undefined variable: data"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add `use($data)` to the closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366081/1227923):

```
User::whereHas('books', function($query) use($data) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $data);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `use`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$data = [1,2,3,4];
echo User::whereHas('books', function($query) use ($data){
        $query->whereIn('id', $data);
     })->get();
}
```

Hope this helps